# How to print a mysqli_fetch_array variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
while($testing = mysqli_fetch_array($sendPasswordQuery)){
echo "'$testing['name']'";
}
```

Hi, I know that the second line is wrong, but how would I print the name column. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second line needs to be formatted as one of the following:

```
echo $testing['name']; // will output Name directly
echo "'{$testing['name']}'"; // will output 'Name' inside a string
echo "'$testing[name]'"; // will output 'Name' in a string,
                         // however the second example is better practice.
```

If you are just echoing the variable and not adding any extra text to it, just use this:

```
echo $testing['name'];
```

Otherwise, I'd suggest the following:

```
echo "Lorem ipsum {$testing['name']} sit amet.";
```

That will output: `Lorem ipsum Name sit amet.`

Comment: Why is the first example best practice?

Comment: I've actually just switched it with the second example. Whilst $testing[name] will work within a string, some common characters used in array indexes will cause the parser to not match them. {$testing['name']} is unambiguous, and will always output the correct result inside a string.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of quotes, all of them outside of the variable are unnecessary:

```
while($testing = mysqli_fetch_array($sendPasswordQuery)){
    echo $testing['name'];
}
```